# notifyObservers(Object arg) in Observable

Tags: java, observer-pattern

Can anyone tell me what type of argument is passed in notifyObserver(Object arg). I mean does it mean I have to passed the argument/Object only which is being watched or anything which is useful for Observer.

Answer (score 2):

Anything which is useful to the Observer

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html#notifyObservers()

> If this object has changed, as indicated by the hasChanged method, then notify all of its observers and then call the clearChanged method to indicate that this object has no longer changed.
>   Each observer has its update method called with two arguments: this observable object and the arg argument.

Comment: Thanks Jorn , One more question will using the Observer Pattern will cause any kind memory related issue. I have seen one blog which mention about this. But others does not mention much about it.

Answer (score 2):

Working on the same problem. This is what I found:

notifyObservers(Object obj): Notifies all observers of the invoking object that it has changed by calling update( ).
obj is passed as an argument to update( ).

Basically, obj that is passed in notifyObservers() will be passed to "update(Observable o, Object arg)", as arg.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-util-observable-class-java/